# Laravel eloquent get items belonging to a certain category

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following table structure

tables

```
 tbl_items
   id
   sub_category_id //foreign key
```

table subcategories

```
  tbl_subcategories
     id
     category_id
     name
```

table categories

```
   tbl_categories
      id
       name
```

As you can see from the above the sub_category_id is a foreign key in products table which relates to the id in the subcategories table. the subcategories table have a category_id which is a foreign key from the categories table

Now i wanted to fetch all items belonging to a certain category.

so i have tried

```
$categories = Categories::where('id',7)->first();
//from categories get subcategoryid
$allsubcategories = Subcategories::where('category_id',$categories->id)->pluck('id')


$allitems = Items::where('status',1)->wherein('sub_category_id',$allsubcategories)
```

The above works. but is there a neater way to do this?

Comment: Use many to many relationship.

Answer (score 2):

define a `hasManyThrough` relationship in the `Category` model to the `Item` model.

```
// on the Category Model
public function items() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Items::class, Subcategories::class);
}
```

then you can access all the `items` belongs to a particular `category`

```
// On your Controller
$category = Categories::where('id',7)->first();
$items = $category->items
```

official documentation - https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 1):

Well you could probably try using Nested Eager Loading, which should be a little more efficent:

```
//Assuming the relationships are named subCategories() on Categories model & items() on Subcategories model
$cat = Categories::where('id', 7)
           ->with('subCategories.items')
           ->get()
           ->first();
```

That should load the category w/ all the subCategories and all the items within each subCategories with the least amount of queries.